# Unable to find an entry point named 'glBindFramebuffer' in DLL 'opengl32.dll'. in MonoGame 3.0

Tags: c#, .net, xna, mono, monogame

Recently I install MonoGame 3.0 on my Laptop. I took a band New "MonoGame Windows OpenGL Project" from project template and try to run it and i got this exception.

```
Unable to find an entry point named 'glBindFramebuffer' in DLL 'opengl32.dll'.
```

The exception was here:

```
 public Game1()
 : base()
 {
   graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);<----|Unable to find an entry point named 'glBindFramebuffer' in DLL 'opengl32.dll'
```

I am installed :

```
MonoDevelop 3.0.6
gtk-sharp-2.12.10.win32
Opentk-2010-10-06
XNAGS40_Setup
jdk-7u9-windows-x64
MonoGame3.0
```

I am using :

```
Windows 7 x64
Visual studio 2012
ASUS A52F Laptop
Graphic : Integrated Intel® GMA HD
```

Does any thing need to install ?

Note : If I use MonoGame 2.5.1.0 then everything works fine. This exception occurs only when I install MonoGmae 30.

Comment: Ususally Intel's GMA is the worst choice for a developer. Suggest you buy a discrete graphics card, or switch to desktop PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/998). You can try to find the installed driver and check its [OpenGL capabilities](http://feedback.wildfiregames.com/report/opengl/). Looks like the drivers only support OpenGL 2.1, and further that support might [not be added](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/811).

You can try to [wrap the instantiation in a try/catch](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/pull/1004), if that works for you.

Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

MonoGame 3.0 requires OpenGL 3.
Try updating your graphics drivers, if that doesn't work then you're out of luck unless you get a new laptop.