# Problems setting up OpenTK in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, opengl, opentk

I am going to develop with [OpenTK](https://opentk.net/) in Visual Studio 2019 to develop 3D graphics with WinForms and make a windows application. However, I am having great difficulty getting it set up correctly. I have installed the OpenTK with NuGet in VS and it's connected to my project. When I follow any tutorial really, I get the same error:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to solve this? I am aware of [this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766944/type-initializer-exception-opentk-and-monogame/) 
already. It did not help me.

The code I'm trying to run now is basicly only this:

```cs
using System;
using OpenTK;

namespace OpenTK_tutorial
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GameWindow window = new GameWindow(640, 480);
            window.Run();
        }
    }
}
```