# Run-Time error with MonoGame / XNA

Tags: c#, xna, runtime, monogame, opentk

I am trying to run some sample code on my Laptop.  I know the sample code works correctly because i have complied it and run it on my PC.

I have installed DirectX / XNA / openAL / Monogame (in this order)

IDE is VS2010

When i open the example code i can compile it without error, when i run it is will crash with:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' occurred in OpenTK.dll

Additional information: Unable to find an entry point named 'glBindFramebuffer' in DLL     'opengl32.dll'.
```

When i break, it crashes at:

```
  graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this)
```

Google search of the error code does not provide very much useful information.

Any help, or suggestions would be great,

Kevin

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558256/unable-to-find-an-entry-point-named-glbindframebuffer-in-dll-opengl32-dll-i

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly my error.  i dont know why Google didnt pick it up for me.  I will try and update video drivers and hope it works.

Comment: Update: No luck, updated driver and does not work.

Comment: Try reinstalling everything, including the OS? By the way, are you by any chance using Windows 8? You know it has some problems with XNA.